# How to use if else in x-magento-template

Tags: x-magento-template

I want to use if, in x-magento-template, I try this code and it shows thí

Code :

```
<% if(fields.branche == ""){ %>
        <div class="right">
            <img style="width: 25px;" src="http://ainem.powered-by-rackspeed.de/pub/media/premium/premiumCrown.png" title="Premium-Filiale mit Angeboten"/>
        </div>
<% } %>
```

Bug :

[image]

Comment: please find below answer,https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/283097/52244 hope this solves your concern.

Comment: mention your magento version

Answer (score 1):

try following way..

```
<script id="some-template" type="text/x-magento-template">
    <% if (fields.branche == "") { %>
        <div class="right">
            <img style="width: 25px;" src="http://ainem.powered-by-rackspeed.de/pub/media/premium/premiumCrown.png" title="Premium-Filiale mit Angeboten"/>
        </div>
    <% } %>
</script>
```

Comment: hi Rakesh Donga, i tryed but it not work

Answer (score 0):

You can use `mage/template` to use these `x-magento-template` JS templates and render them .

```
define([
    "jquery",
    "mage/template"
], function($, mageTemplate) {
    var warningTemplate = mageTemplate('#some-template');
    $('body').append(warningTemplate); // for example added body as refenece area, that can update as per need
});
```

And the #some-template is:
not have much idea about conditional part `fields.branche == ""` so instead of added `1 means true` in condition to make it work (or to test).

```
 <script id="some-template" type="text/x-magento-template">
    <% if(1){ %>
        <div class="right">
            <img style="width: 25px;" src="https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_92x30dp.png" title="Google"/>
        </div>
<% } %>
</script>
```

> For **live example** see pdp 
>   `data-role="cart-item-warning-message-template"` on script 
>   (**warningTemplate**) and template calling js is
>   `Magento_Catalog/js/catalog-add-to-cart`